# Facebook AudienceNetwork loaded failure: No fill, Error Message "No fill", what is the reason about FaceBook android Advertise?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

Facebook AudienceNetwork loaded failure: No fill, Error Message "No fill", what is the reason about FaceBook android Advertise? And facebook ad offten shows me load frequency, the frenquent has limits?

Comment: No fill. We are not able to serve ads to this person. Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a12. If you are integrating Audience Network for the first time, you can use test ads https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing.

Comment: Try to add the test device hash in Facebook Ad Settings

Answer (score 35):

You need to add a test device. Go to logcat and type `Facebook` and you will see a message like this, which is also the solution:

> When testing your app with Facebook's ad units you must specify the
>   device hashed ID to ensure the delivery of test ads, add the following
>   code before loading an ad:
>   **AdSettings.addTestDevice("328404cebf50ec1fdb05795c0007a8a7")**;

So add this to your onCreate method:

```
AdSettings.addTestDevice("328404cebf50ec1fdb05795c0007a8a7");
```

(Don't forget to use your own hash id.)

Comment: what about the "testing with real ads" mentioned in facebook guide? I am able to load ads by adding `AdSettings.addTestDevice()` but not able to test with real ads without the line

Comment: yes same issue. by adding AdSettings.addTestDevice() this testing ad display but still in live app got error "No Fill" is there any solution ? my question is this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055218/how-to-resolve-error-1001-no-fill-using-facebook-audience-network-in-android?noredirect=1#comment81059710_47055218

Comment: I'm not sure but could this have anything to do with the updated Facebook audience ads? There was a message in my FB developer account to apply/update the correct settings in order to serve ads.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue in testing mode with Mediation implmentation, Mine is resolved after login the test user in the facebook application and the Facebook Ads stated loading and showing, I am not getting No Fill error at all.

Comment: where to get this hash id in android phone ? @AlexioVay

Answer (score 6):

This means we are not able to serve ads to this person. This could occur because:

- The person testing has not logged into the native Facebook app on their mobile device
- The person testing has enabled "Limit Ad Tracking" (iOS only) or has selected "Opt out of interest-based ads" (Android only) in their device settings.
- We don't have ad inventory to show for that person
- Note that if you can see test ads, your implementation works correctly and people will be able to see ads in your app once it's live.

you can get more clarification [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#faq_1204719862895859)

Answer (score 4):

Filling in payout details fixed this for me.

If you want to display real Ads, you have to fill in your payout details.

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem in my application but this helps me

Ref: [Step 4: Check for Error Codes of Production Ads Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing)

```
Facebook Error : No fill
1001 - No Fill
```

This is a common error seen while testing, and relates to a "No Fill" response; the most common reason for this is the user is not logged in to the Facebook App when testing your mobile app or not logged in to the Facebook mobile website when testing your mobile website.

- Error 1001 - No Fill. May be due to one or more of the following:
- User not logged into Native Facebook App on Mobile Device
- Limit Ad Tracking turned on (iOS)
- Opt out of interest-based ads turned on (Android)
- No Ad Inventory for current user
- Your testing device must have the native Facebook application
  installed.

Your application should attempt to make another request after 30 seconds.

And Sometimes According to me

- If your ad account newly created then wait some time like 1 hour or more 
  after some time you will get some better response

I know its late answer but this may helps other people who new in android and Using Facebook Ads

Answer (score 2):

If you see

> When testing your app with Facebook's ad units you must specify the
>   device hashed ID to ensure the delivery of test ads, add the following
>   code before loading an ad:
>   AdSettings.addTestDevice("328404cebf50ec1fdb05795c0007a8a7");

This may happen because of this:

```
FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, Your Device have Facebook app installed and logged in. And also make sure, the developer account that created Ads and the Facebook user logged in the device are same. If not read
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing/

Answer (score 0):

try to this sdk verison.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and it's resolved, Please follow the below steps for the live ads issue:

1. Check the SDK version and use the latest one
2. Check and confirm live SDK key
3. Upload your application in store
4. Enable live mode in Facebook ads console
5. Fill proper details in testing test

The above steps are upto date, then after the test the application after 48 hours of the time of app publishing.

I wasted more than one month to resolve the No Fill error.

Answer (score 0):

(Only relevant if you're in the Europe?)

- On your phone, go to the Facebook app
- Go to Settings & Privacy
- Permissions > Cookies
- Enable "Our cookies on other apps and websites"

On my end, as soon as this is turned off, Audience Network fails to fill any ads.

Answer (score 0):

To request a test ad, you have to use the following test ad type string to concatenate the placement ID with '#'

Example

InterstitialAd(context,"VID_HD_16_9_46S_APP_INSTALL#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID")

For getting more information about available test ads visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/test/test-device

Answer (score 0):

Add this line for display test ad

```
AdSettings.setTestMode(BuildConfig.DEBUG);
```