# How to resolve Error = 1001 "No Fill" using Facebook Audience Network in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network

I have an Android version of my app and integrated FAN into my Application.
It worked for some months but now it's displaying "**NO FILL**"

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=**1001 "No fill"** 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=**No fill**, 
FBAdErrorDetailKey={ msg = "**No fill**"}}
```

And no FAN ad is shown. If I put a **testing ID** then it's displaying, but only on my device, not for another device.

How to resolve this problem "No Fill"?

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
```

Mentioned in build.gradle
I've seen many questions regarding this but unable to find an answer.

I've already seen below links:

1. [Facebook AudienceNetwork loaded failure: No fill, Error Message "No fill", what is the reason about FaceBook android Advertise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664036/facebook-audiencenetwork-loaded-failure-no-fill-error-message-no-fill-what)
2. [facebook audience network testing on test flight No Fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611887/facebook-audience-network-testing-on-test-flight-no-fill)
3. [Audience Network iOS Ads Suddenly Become "No Fill"](https://www.facebook.com/help/audiencenetwork/community/question/?id=105826316763239)
4. [Facebook Audience Network returns "No fill"](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=1494007767293505)
5. [Testing Audience Network Implementation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing/)

Comment: Try using the Audience Network Requests Debugger https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing/ Also, there were a bunch of changes to Audience Network recently such as introduction of Ad Spaces, etc. Do check your app dashboard to see if there's anything pending there.

Comment: Yeah but nothing to missing in my code it's worked before couple of months but instantly it's gave error. in above question description i was already mentioned this link. i referred this. @Bangdel

Comment: Did you check the App Dashboard for any warnings?

Comment: @InsaneCat, any method for your problem? I same problem. I intergated FAN to ios/android app but only work on iOS, android always no fill ads. try to add a tester to dashboard, login with this tester + use my app. but always get message "Not started - please send an ad request" in dashboard.!!

Comment: @TuanHuynh still i didn't got any solutions. if i'll get then posted here. don't worry and give UP so question going to popular and we get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.It solves my problem .
[you have to follow this steps for solve this problem](https://www.facebook.com/help/audiencenetwork/126177127960965) In this all screenshot and steps are given .

May this help you. Because of the update in facebook developer console in **audience Network** tab **ad-spaces** group that is newly created from **placements**. You have to follow this steps. Might it helps others.

I have also posted screenshot along with steps details.

***here Click on up-grouped for appName and then follow steps.***

1. **Tick** check-mark box for any one ad then **make placements** button will be enable.
   [image]
2. Enter name and description related to where ad will display in your app and then click on **Move** Button
   [image]
3. After move one ad you can also select other ad from un-grouped ad and move it to ad-spaces , here it will shoe you choice for move to **existing** or **create new one** ad-space.
   [image]
4. If you want to create new one then select radio button for new one . and click move after enter name and description.
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

I got same error when I want testing ad.

**Error: No Fill error code [1001] No fill. We are not able to serve ads to this person.**

I didn't register for AD because my app is not live at that moment. So, I don't have advertise Id . I'm using test id `"YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID"` for demo propose when I got that error. So only test id is not enough for get testing ads in Facebook Ad.

I found solution for that as below.

When You're `initialize` AudienceNetworkAds then just enable **testmode** that's it.

> AdSettings.setTestMode(true)

```
class AudienceNetworkInitializeHelper : AudienceNetworkAds.InitListener {

        override fun onInitialized(result: AudienceNetworkAds.InitResult) {
            Log.d(AudienceNetworkAds.TAG, result.message)
        }

        companion object {

            internal fun initialize(context: Context) {
                if (!AudienceNetworkAds.isInitialized(context)) {
                    if (DEBUG) {
                        AdSettings.turnOnSDKDebugger(context)
                        AdSettings.setTestMode(true)// for get test ad in your device
                    }

                    AudienceNetworkAds
                            .buildInitSettings(context)
                            .withInitListener(AudienceNetworkInitializeHelper())
                            .initialize()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

> My audience-network-sdk is `implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.4.0'`
>   and It's work also in **5.6.0** .

Comment: Thanks! Should know this earlier!

Answer (score 3):

You need add the test device to test it before your app approved by Facebook. Here is how you can get the device hash.

```
NSLog(@"the test device hash is %@",[FBAdSettings testDeviceHash]);
```

Run the app and copy the `testDeviceHash` from logs then add it to `FBAdSettings`.

```
[FBAdSettings addTestDevice:@"YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_HASH_CODE_HERE"];
```

> You need to do it before you init the `FBAdView`

Comment: But this is how it workout for me. this may help others.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue. My steps:

**1. Make sure to set the test device hash in your code**

- Start by testing from the xCode simulator and not your device to make sure it works well.
- Add this log somewhere (e.g. viewDidLoad) to display your xCode simulator device hash:

```c
NSLog(@"%@",[FBAdSettings testDeviceHash]);
```

- Then set it in your code:

```c
[FBAdSettings addTestDevice:@"YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_HASH"];
```

**2. Make sure you're using the correct placementID**

- Go to Monetization Manager home page
- Expand Integration on the left menu
- Click on Properties
- Copy the ID of your properties and paste it in your code:

```c
- (void)loadNativeAd{
    FBNativeAd *nativeAd = [[FBNativeAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:@"YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID"];
    nativeAd.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"%@",[FBAdSettings testDeviceHash]);
    [FBAdSettings addTestDevice:@"YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_HASH"];
    [nativeAd loadAd];
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved, until I logged in with my admin account into facebook app and download again my application from google play.

A few suggestions for you problem:
"No Fill" with error code 1001 -  is a common error, FAN not returning ads to your ad.

Ensure the following things:
 - Ad Status with Placement ID (Audience Network> Ad Space> Placement) must be "Enabled and received ad request recently" (1)
- Your Ad Status must be reviewed and approved by facebook. (2)

If (1), you can try to disable and enable again.
If (2), you must download the facebook app from google play + login with administrator account / or developer / testers (added in Roles tab)), I recommend login with admin account; and download your app directly from google play.

You said your application has been active for some time, and the above things is right, the last is send a message to the Audience Network Team and they will reply in 3-5 business days.

[image]

Comment: @RaviYadav I also can't get mediation ad. I tired both FB Banner AdView and Dfp mediation, FB AdView get Error code 1001, but Dfp mediation not get any response. How to debug for this one? Any guide, please refer.

Comment: @Tuan Huynh Any debug guide or tool? Please guide to me.

Comment: @Sakthi On monetization manager you will find option "ad request debugger" where you will find app request from your app. And I managed to solve this error when I changed the type of ad . ie from rectangle to some other type  and it worked for me. I haven't change the code just the type on facebook.

Comment: @RaviYadav Thanks for your fast response. Where i get "monetization manager"?. I used only banner Ad,  Adsize : 320x50 and 728x90.

Comment: @Sakthi just google monetziation manager and you will be redirected to the facebook console , add your credential and you are good to go.
https://business.facebook.com/login/web/

Comment: @RaviYadav Okay I'll check out that one.

Comment: @RaviYadav I start debugged and look on logs, still get same error, "no fill".

Comment: @RaviYadav Mediation Ad not shown. Ad show when directly call Facebook AdView with placement Id. FB Ad not auto refresh. How to find mediation issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this version,and check that it's working or not

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'
```