# Facebook Native Ad - Native ad failed to load: No fill

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

I've integrated facebook native ad by following this guidelines
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-native

It works fine on android 6 and lower versions but it Shows me No fill error with Android 7 and higher versions with release APK

I'm using this SDK 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.2.0'

Already referred this link [Facebook AudienceNetwork loaded failure: No fill, Error Message "No fill", what is the reason about FaceBook android Advertise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664036/facebook-audiencenetwork-loaded-failure-no-fill-error-message-no-fill-what)

Answer (score 0):

try this sdk verion and check.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

work for me

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.5.0'

add this line on your manifest file in Application tag

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

add xml config file in xml

```
 <network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to update the library from gradle and the error will disappear

Comment: I'm using the latest version already
'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.2.0'